# Select is not populating via API call in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I'm very new to Vue and I'm doing Vue just because I need to use it in a project. Right now, I'm trying to populate a 'Select' by performing an API call. However, it is not working. Here's the code.

```
<template>
    <form method="POST">
        <label>
            Website Name
        </label>
        <select name="website_id">
           <option v-for="item in this.websiteData" :value="item.id">{{item.domain}}</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        async beforeMount() {
            await fetch('/api/get-website').then(res=>res.json()).then(data=>this.websiteData = data.map(item=>item));
           console.log(this.websiteData);
        },
        // name: "FormComponent"
        data(){
            return {
                websiteData: [],
                postData: null
            }
        },
    methods: {

    }
   }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <select name="website_id">
       <option v-for="item in websiteData" :value="item.id"> 
       {{item.domain}}
       </option>
    </select>
```

Typo in websiteData. In template you can access variables without  *this*.

Comment: It didn't work. The Select list is still not populated.